# how to unjoin to the domain, rename the PC and then join it to the new domain in one script

Tags: powershell, psexec

Anyone who has a PSEXEC or Powershell script to unjoin to the domain, rename the PC and then join it to the new domain in one script. We're migrating to a new server/domain and needs to rename also all the PCs using a standard PC name before joining it to the new domain.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Give it a try and show your [mcve] if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward via [the `Win32_ComputerSystem` WMI class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem):

```
# Fetch the `Win32_ComputerSystem` instance on localhost
$CS = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem

# Unjoin old domain
$CS |Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName UnjoinDomainOrWorkGroup -Arguments @{
  FUnjoinOptions = 4
  Password = $DomainPassword
  UserName = $DomainUser
}

# Rename the computer
$CS |Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Rename -Arguments @{
  Name = $NewComputerName
}

# Join the new domain
$CS |Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName JoinDomainOrWorkGroup -Arguments @{
  AccountOU = 'OU=Computers,DC=new,DC=domain,DC=tld'
  FJoinOptions = 0
  Name = 'new.domain.tld'
  Password = $NewDomainPassword
  UserName = $NewDomainUser
}
```